# What to use instead of PrintWriter?

Tags: java

Here is my code that I have which is pretty simple and to the point:

```
public void sendMessage(String message)
{
    writer.println(message);
    writer.flush();
}
```

I don't really like to use PrintWriter cause it tends to swallow IOExceptions, this is really the only thing I'm using it for besides sending byte arrays. What can I use instead that won't consume IOExceptions and will still give me the functionality of PrintWriter?

Comment: What part of the functionality do you need? Line feed? Formatting? Automatic flushing?

Comment: i think there is not anything does not swallows IOExceptions. if try/catch if you try/catch bother, could use a static method that encapsulates try/catch

Comment: @mulax: he's not complaining about it *throwing* exceptions, it's that it *doesn't* throw exceptions - you have to query using `checkError()`.

Comment: I thought, won't consume==won't throw

Comment: @mulax roughly speaking ... throwing an exception *produces* an exception - *consume* is the opposite of *produce*.  Won't consume != won't throw.  (Actually, we are being a little bit loose with out terminology here.  Strictly speaking we should be talking about exceptions propagating, or being caught.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend using a plain `Writer` or a `BufferedWriter`

```
public void writeMessage(BufferedWriter bw, String message) throws IOException {
    bw.write(message);
    bw.newline();
    bw.flush();
}
```

or

```
public void writeMessage(Writer writer, String message) throws IOException {
    writer.write(message);
    writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
    writer.flush();
}
```

But obviously it depends on what functionality of `PrintWriter` you want to retain.

Comment: Does Writer and/or BufferedWriter tend to suppress IOExcepitons?

Comment: Nope. Read the javadocs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html You would find that the write() method throws IOException

Comment: In fact all of the methods in both versions can throw IOException.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retain PrintWriter and yet check whether any exception has occurred, you can use the checkError() method of PrintWriter to do so. For example, using your own code:

```
public void sendMessage(String message)
{
    try{
        writer.println(message);
    }finally{
           //checkError flushes the stream if it's not closed and checks its error state.
        if(writer.checkError()){ 
            //Your error handling code here
        }
    }
}
```

The other way would be to use BufferedReader as @Thilo had suggested in his comment. It would again depend on the functionalities that you would want to retain.

In case you use an instance of BufferedWriter, you would've the write() methods to work with, which do throw IOException. [Read more about them in the javadocs here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html)